# Unable to use sed to customize buffer size in mariadb Dockerfile

Tags: sed, docker

I'm trying to customize a mariadb container so that it has an increased innodb buffer size.  My ideal scenario would be to use `sed` so I don't have to maintain a duplicate `my.cnf` config file.

Here's my Dockerfile, but it doesn't replace the value like I'd expect and I"m not sure what I'm doing wrong...

```
FROM mariadb:10.1

RUN sed -ri 's/innodb_buffer_pool_size\\ =\\ 256M/innodb_buffer_pool_size\\ =\\ 512M/g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf \
    && cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf | grep innodb;
```

The output of this is:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 231.9 MB
Step 1 : FROM mariadb:10.1
 ---> 9a0138c02438
Step 2 : RUN sed -ri 's/innodb_buffer_pool_size\\ =\\ 256M/innodb_buffer_pool_size\\ =\\ 512M/g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf     && cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf | grep innodb;
 ---> Running in eaedaf2837ff
#innodb_log_file_size   = 50M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files       = 400
innodb_io_capacity      = 400
innodb_flush_method     = O_DIRECT
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
 ---> b0e479c55581
Removing intermediate container eaedaf2837ff
Successfully built b0e479c55581
```

I've tried escaping the spaces with `\\` and not escaping the spaces with no luck.

Comment: Why on earth did you try escaping spaces? Has there ever been anything you've done in the past where you HAD to escape spaces? That just seems like a very random thing to suddenly decide might be a good idea so I'm wondering if you've been doing something wrong in the past (e.g. not quoting a string) and found you could get it to "work" by escaping spaces rather than doing it the right way, whatever that was!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't escape the spaces like you do:

1. spaces don't need escaping
2. escaping with `\\` inside simple quotes actually create a `\` char. No wonder why your regex doesn't work.

That works:

```
sed -i 's/innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M/innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M/g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

1. if you really have to escape something, that will be only because of regex, not the shell, because you have used simple quotes and the shell does not interpret the contents
2. you don't need the `-r, --regexp-extended` switch for this particular example. regexp extended includes stuff like forward lookup, ... not needed here.

Improvement: use group to recall the matched value. Less maintenance if you have to change the parameter name

```
sed -i 's/\(innodb_buffer_pool_size\) = 256M/\1 = 512M/g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

or match several parameter names

```
sed -i 's/\(innodb_buffer_pool_size\|some_other_param\) = 256M/\1 = 512M/g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```